# pdfkit doesn't installed or worked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, pdfkit

I try to use pdfkit in python3, but have some trouble with installing or importing of this module.

```
old@old:~/Desktop/some$ pip install pdfkit
Downloading/unpacking pdfkit
  Downloading pdfkit-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pdfkit
Successfully installed pdfkit
Cleaning up...
old@old:~/Desktop/some$ python3 second.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pdfkit
ImportError: No module named 'pdfkit'
old@old:~/Desktop/some$
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: can you show the result of `which pip` ?? it looks your pip has downloaded a pdfkit of python2x `Downloading pdfkit-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: Are you using `pip2`?

Comment: old@old:~/Desktop/some$ which

pip /usr/local/bin/pip

old@old:~/Desktop/some$ pip -V

pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: @user3584659 So, use `pip3 install pdfkit`. your `pip` is a link of `pip2`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the previous comment but not clear enough to find it.

For python3, use pip3, like: `pip3 install pdfkit`